# is I need to purchase Both Paypal and Braintree Account for Paypal Integration?

Tags: paypal, braintree

I have Paypal Account. can I integrate Paypal Payment Gateway only using Paypal Account or should I need to purchase Braintree Account too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), you only need a PayPal business account to receive the payments. From a native app you can use the new [Native Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/).

---

[Braintree Direct](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct) is a separate gateway product, with other features. The Braintree SDK, which does not require a Braintree account for us with only PayPal payments, was also useful for integrating PayPal Checkout in native apps before the Native Checkout SDK was available.